# Raspi camera module V3 with Octopi

Tags: pi-4, camera, raspicam, picamera, libcamera

Recently purchased raspberry pi **camera module 3 NOIR**. My plan was to use it for **octopi** (octoprint), however, i tried my best but couldn’t make it work, and followed many of pages on net but no result (**note** that i could enable the camera on raspberry pi OS, but not on octopi). My enquiry is regarding steps for enabling the camera in octopi and use it for streaming in octoprint (using latest version of octopi, and **raspberry pi 4**) . does anyone knows?

Answer (score 1):

Looks like it's not currently possible/supported. The new module 3 does not work with the legacy camera stack. See https://forums.raspberrypi.com/viewtopic.php?p=2070744 for more info.